# Lost my schema.rb! Can it be regenerated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git

Due to some deployment issues I stopped tracking schema.rb in git. Somehow I have stuffed this up and somewhere along the way my schema.rb file has disappeared.

Is there a way of regenerating schema.rb from the database or from the migrations? I would prefer not to lose the existing data.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

If you run a `rake -T` it will list all possible rake tasks for your Rails project. One of them is *db:schema:dump* which will recreate the schema.rb for the Rails app from the database.

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: Great thanks, many answers but looks like you were first (just) so tick for you. Just curious, does this generate the schema from the database itself or from the migrations?

Comment: From the database itself, so be careful if there are changes that happened outside of the migrations.

Comment: schema.rb still contains empty schema after `rake db:schema:dump` on rails 2.0

Comment: My schema.rb file remains exactly the same after running the above commands

Answer (score 62):

Careful,

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

will dump the current DB schema **FROM the DB**. This means that if you made any changes to your migrations, they will **NOT** be reflected in schema.rb file which is not what you want IMO.

If you want to re-create the schema from the migrations, do the following:

```
rake db:drop  # ERASES THE DATABASE !!!! 
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: That would result in loss of data, which the OP said they wanted to avoid. Additionally, as Colin points out, regenerating the database purely from the migrations is potentially a very bad idea because of the increased possibility of running in to odd dependency issues (generally speaking). If there are pending migrations, it would likely be best to run those last migrations on the development machine, and then run the `rake db:schema:dump` command.

Comment: Every canvas is clearly explained in my answer. I've got bitten EXACTLY by running only schema:dump and not getting a clean schema. The OP is talking about tracking the schema in a CVS. I would like to have my schema aligned with my definitions in my migrations and not an obsolete version from a production DB or an old development DB

Answer (score 12):

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

I think this is still valid in Rails 3 - it regenerates the schema.rb from the database.

Answer (score 12):

**RAILS 5 Way:**

```
rails db:schema:dump
```

or if you Encounter **Gem::LoadError** then:

```
bundle exec rails db:schema:dump
```

**Note:**

in rails 5 it is recommended that task are generated/executed by using `rails` instead of `rake`, this is just to remember, rails generated task are of extension `.rake` see in `lib/tasks/myTask.rake`. which means these task can also be executed by prepending `rake`.

Answer (score 7):

If you regenerate `schema.rb` locally, you should be alright. It simply holds a representation of the structure of your database tables. The data itself is not contained in this file.

To regenerate your `schema.rb` file, run:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

Then simply commit the new `schema.rb` file and you should be in good shape!

Answer (score 7):

Directly from the schema.rb file itself:

> If you need to create the application database on another
>   system, you should be using `db:schema:load`, not running all the migrations
>   from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
>   you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).

So do NOT do the suggestion of `rake db:migrate`, which was suggested in the - at the time of this writing - lowest rated answer.

Comment: You would probably want to run the last few pending migrations if there are any on your development machine before regenerating the schema, but yes regenerating the database purely from the migrations is a very bad idea, especially since that would result in loss of data.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem where my old schema was not refreshing even if I deleted migration.

So, what I did was dropping all existing tables in the database and migrating them again. Then running "db:schema:load" command gave me a fresh schema.rb.

```
drop table my_table_name // deleted them individually
rake db:migrate
rake db:schema:dump // re-created a new schema
```