# Rails: I modified my migration file (Bad, I know)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I recently started using Rails, and created a few Models using the CLI which in turn created some migrations.

I ran the `rake db:migrate` command after adding all my columns in there, and then realized that I'd left out the associations.

**So what did I do?**
I went ahead and edited the migrations to include those keys.

I ran `rake db:migrate` again, and nothing changed in the schema.

Then I ran `rake db:reset` and then `rake db:setup`.

When that didn't work, I deleted my `schema.rb` (the darn thing wouldn't get updated!) and tried [recreating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731585/lost-my-schema-rb-can-it-be-regenerated/). When I realized that didn't work, I dropped the database, and killed the schema.

Now I'm stuck with some manually modified migrations, no `schema.rb` and no database.

> How do I get the modified migrations to generate a schema, and play nice with Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **development** it does not matter to drop and rebuild your database. I do it often and I even have a rake task for that. The 3 command to chain are:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
# And a 4rth optional command to rebuild your test database
rake db:test:prepare
```

With this you should be good

**Next time** you need to modify a migration manually after migrating it, you should process by:

1. `rake db:rollback`
2. edit your migration
3. `rake db:migrate`

Following those steps will save you some headaches

---

Bonus info:

After you deployed your migration to your **production** server you cannot manually modify it, hence you must write another migration that will perform the modification (adding columns, etc...)