# Trying to add Hstore migration gives "StandardError" in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add an Hstore "Details" column to my products table, as follows:

```
# 20180202133309_add_hstore_extension.rb
class AddHstoreExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    enable_extension "hstore"
  end
  def self.down
    disable_extension "hstore"
  end
end
```

Migration was ran on the above, and then the one below

```
# 20180202133435_add_hstore_to_products.rb
class AddHstoreToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :products, :details, :hstore
    add_index :products, :details, using: :gin
  end
end
```

I thought it might be necessary to run the `enable_extension` migration before the column addition migration, but either way it gives the following error in my Schema

```
# schema.rb
# Could not dump table "products" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'hstore' for column 'details'
```

The table still works fine in my application though, so is this an error I can just ignore?  I don't like not being able to view the table in my Schema.

Answer (score 1):

[Lost my schema.rb! Can it be regenerated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731585/lost-my-schema-rb-can-it-be-regenerated)

Or to save you time, try from terminal:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: That didn't work, thanks for the link though!  I'm going to have to do some consolidating of my current "test" platform and create some seeds so I can dump the whole DB and try from the beginning.  I'll also note that it's only the `Products` table that is throwing this error; none of the others are.